# What's special about this image?

Tags: steganography

There's something very special hidden in this image. You will **definitely** know when you find it.

[image: special image]

(I know Stack Exchange lossily compresses images but I've checked and no pixels have been altered.)

Finding traces of the secret might not be that hard. The ideal answer will point to the Stack Exchange question that I took data from to help generate this image (and possibly point to another that can help "decode" it).

**Hint:**

> I can reveal the secret with this 20 line Python program. I've replaced the most telling bits with `???`:
>
> ```
> from PIL import Image
> i = Image.open('hidden.png')
> d = i.load()
> x, y = ???, ???
> while ???:
>     oldX, oldY = x, y
>     if ???:
>         ???
>     elif ???:
>         ???
>     elif ???:
>         ???
>     else:
>         ???
>     d[oldX, oldY] = (0, 0, 0)
> for x in range(i.size[0]):
>     for y in range(i.size[1]):
>         if ???:
>             d[x, y] = (255, 255, 255)
> i.save('revealed.png')
> ```

Comment: Was the original file a `.png` also?

Comment: Does the answer have anything to do with changing bases?

Comment: @Bobson Not really. You may find a png that is similar to the original but you won't find an exact original because I had to remake it to make sure it was pixel perfect.

Comment: @rr Nope, it doesn't

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> This image represents instructions for a snake that fills the visited pixels with black paint.
>
> - Red color means "go right"
> - Aqua color means "go left"
>
>   Blue color means "go up"
>
>   Green color means "go down"
>
> The snake starts at the center of the image. (Edit: looks like it can start anywhere but the borders. The images below were produced using center as the starting point.)
>  The snake stops as soon as it proceeds out of the image boundaries.
>  After we're done, we fill remaining unvisited pixels with white paint.

---

> What is interesting is what happens if the snake visits a block that was already visited: it turns out that no matter if we go left, right, down or up, we still see the result pretty clearly.
>
> Going left:
> [image: Going left]
> Going down:
> [image: Going down]
> Going right:
> [image: Going right]
> Going up:
> [image: Going up]

---

> ```
> #!/bin/python
> from PIL import Image
>
> colors = [(255, 0, 0), (0, 255, 255), (127, 0, 255), (127, 255, 0)]
>
> i = Image.open('hidden.png')
> d = i.load()
> w, h = i.size
> x, y = w >> 1, h >> 1
> while x >= 0 and y >= 0 and x < w and y < h:
>     oldX, oldY = x, y
>     if d[x,y] == colors[0]:
>         x += 1
>     elif d[x,y] == colors1:
>         x -= 1
>     elif d[x,y] == colors2:
>         y += 1
>     elif d[x,y] == colors3:
>         y -= 1
>     elif d[x,y] == (0,0,0):
>         y -= 1 #or whatever
>     else:
>         raise Exception('Bad color: ' + str(d[x,y]))
>     d[oldX, oldY] = (0, 0, 0)
>
> for x in range(w):
>     for y in range(h):
>         if d[x, y] != (0, 0, 0):
>             d[x, y] = (255, 255, 255)
> i.save('revealed.png')
> ```

Comment: This is essentially it :D The pixels that aren't part of the snake are actually random colors (of the 4) so there's no guarantee that they will lead to the snake. Good job! (Though I'll still wait for someone to figure out which two SE questions I hinted at.)

Comment: You shouldn't create an answer which is ALL spoiler tags without any significant text outside.

Answer (score 16):

> Putting it through a [magic eye finder](http://magiceye.ecksdee.co.uk/) gives a faint image of a smiling face, perhaps the Mona Lisa.
>
>  [image]

Comment: Wow. That algorithm has no (intentional) relation to the image. I'm surprised it shows so much.

Comment: Wait? That is not the solution? You are saying this is meant to represent something else, but by chance also contains Mona Lisa?

Comment: Well it depends on how that website works. It might output some random things.

Comment: This [code golf question](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/33172/american-gothic-in-the-palette-of-mona-lisa-rearrange-the-pixels) could be what Calvin is referencing, but I don't understand what he wants to do with it. (It is #5 on the highest vote list.)

Comment: @LarsEbert Mona Lisa *is* the hidden thing, but there's a simpler way to reveal her in a *much* crisper form.

Comment: @Len The question I took data from to generate the image is not my own (the "decoder" however...)

Comment: Well, [this result](http://imgur.com/WHDlJE9) is achieved only playing with saturation and colors. I've resized the image since it's more visible when smaller.